# Lock private object or the hashset itself?

Tags: c#, locking

Assume that i have the hashset below

```
   HashSet<string> hsWaitingToBeFetched = new HashSet<string>();
```

Now i am doing multithreading programming so i have to lock this in order to sync objects

**I can lock this with both way are there any performance difference ?**

```
private Object lockHashset = new Object();
lock(lockHashset)
{
// do stuff here
}
```

or

```
lock(hsWaitingToBeFetched)
{
// do stuff here
}
```

Comment: If you need to know which will be more performant, you should consider trying both and measuring. Note that choosing which object to lock on is more of an issue from a *program correctness* standpoint, rather than a performance standpoint.

Comment: Is the hash set private? And is there ever a situation in which the hash set *itself* changes? That is, do you change the value of the variable that refers to the set, or do you merely change the contents of the set?

Comment: You could use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte>` instead, simply ignore the `Value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*There will be no performance difference<sup>1</sup>..* the semantic difference will be if some *other* code also locks on the HashSet if it is exposed.

I think it is more clear to use a separate lock object in such a case:

1. Clearer intent - depends on scenario
2. <del>Can hide lock object (private) but expose HashSet</del> This should be disregarded without *very* careful consideration - locking only for (private) updating a (public) HashSet is not correctly synchronized.
3. Avoid surprises if a type locks on itself
4. Usable even when re-assigning the HashSet member

However, because a separate lock object *doesn't* lock on the HashSet, if something else expects that it does ..

---

<sup>1</sup> The new lock object creation cost is ignorable. The CLR enters a monitor in the same manner for both cases described.

Comment: I don't understand point #2. If you expose the hash set and not the lock object then how is the code you expose it to going to use it safely?

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks for the challenge - I can't come up with any non-convoluted use-cases and have struck out the item. (I was *sure* I had a good point in mind when I wrote it, but on retrospection it seems misguided ..)

Comment: The usual situation where you want to both expose an object and have a lock associated with it is hinted at in your third item: when the object that is logically locked is of type `Type`.  It can be very difficult to *not* expose a type, and therefore the locked object should be private to ensure that *only code inside the type locks itself*.